# Gradle set ext property in one task and use it in another

Tags: gradle

I have several tasks which executes different SQL scripts via psql.

```java
task runScript1(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "psql -f script1.sql"
}

task runScript2(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "psql -f script2.sql"
}
```

Now I want to write one generic exec task and pass only the script name to it.

```java
ext {
  scriptName = ''
}

task runScriptGeneric(type: Exec) {
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "psql -f ${scriptName}"
}

task runScript1() {
  scriptName = 'script1.sql'
}
runScript1.finalizedBy runScriptGeneric

task runScript2() {
  scriptName = 'script2.sql'
}
runScript2.finalizedBy runScriptGeneric
```

Unfortunately this approach is not working. The `scriptName` stays empty in the `runScriptGeneric` task.

---

I suspect this has to do with the `Exec` type because the following simple task working well.

```java
ext {
  scriptName = ''
}

task runScriptGeneric() {
  doLast {
    println "${scriptName}"
  }
}

task runScript1() {
  doLast {
    scriptName = 'script1.sql'
  }
}
runScript1.finalizedBy runScriptGeneric

task runScript2() {
  doLast {
    scriptName = 'script2.sql'
  }
}
runScript2.finalizedBy runScriptGeneric
```

I do not want do pass it over as a command line parameter (`-PscriptName`), because I want to keep the individual tasks for each script. Is there any other way to pass the `scriptName` from each individual task to the generic task?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not an answer to my question, but it's a solution I can live with.

I've created a dynamic task instead of passing the variable to the executing script:

```java
['Script1', 'Script2'].each {taskName ->
  task "run${taskName}"(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "psql -f ${taskName}"
  }
}
```